# Find the extended "ver" information for remote Windows computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, psexec, wmic, windows-update

Windows 10.0.16299 has added a new "Update Build Revision" ("UBR") number to the ouput of the 'ver' command:

As of 12/17/2017, a fully updated Windows 10 computer reports:

`C:\> ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]`

After spending many hours updating workstations on my network, I discovered that less than 25% of my workstations had actually installed all of the pending updates.

I very badly want to get these updates installed over the weekend to avoid user frustration during the week.

I had a mix of `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.15]`, `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.98]`, and quite a few that failed to update completely and still showed `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]` (these had to be updated using a fresh ISO downloaded using the Media Creation Tool).

The UBR ".125" seems critical, as it is a single indicator that the system is fully and successfully updated with all of the latest patches.

WMIC, PowerShell, and SystemInfo do not include this information anywhere in their output - they report only "10.0.16299" - the OS and Build Number.

The only way I've found to get the UBR value is to use "psexec" to run the "ver" command directly on the remote system:

`psexec \\remotepc cmd /c ver`

 -- but this takes 23 seconds per system, which seems slow...

Is there a faster way to get the the UBR number, or the exact results of 'ver' from a remote computer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!

I don't have remote powershell scripting enabled, but I seem to have remote registry enabled.

I can read the value of UBR from remote systems without any delay using 'reg.exe':

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3 usebackq" %%h in (`reg query "\\%1\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v UBR`) do (
  set /a UBR=%%h 
  echo %UBR%
)
```

If I create 'readubr.bat' containing the above code, then:

```
C:\> readubr.bat localhost
125

c:\> readubr.bat ss_ccstation
125

C:\> readubr.bat ss_shared
125
```

Comment: There is a potential problem with this method of checking UBR.  

On the last system that I updated, the UBR registry key did not exist.  

I logged in on the system, and the UBR value was still missing.  

I rebooted: it was still missing.  

It appeared after my next login...

Comment: Nice solution. Re potential problem: are you saying that no updates were installed between noticing the missing UBR value and it eventually appearing? A quick hint re what it takes to enable remote registry access may be helpful. Consider adding all add'l info directly to the answer and self-accepting it.

Comment: Yes - no update installs, just a couple reboots and logins  It's possible that the 'reg' command was returning an error -- readubr.bat needs updating to check for that.  During the day today I checked another system and got no response, then checked again and got the expected "125" -- making me think there's more I don't understand here...

Comment: As for remote registry access -- I'm pretty sure I set that in Group Policy in my active directory at some point in the last 10 years...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're looking for the W10 *UBR* (UpdateBuildRevision) version number.

**If your remote computers are set up for PowerShell remoting**, you can use (e.g., for remote machine `remotepc`, from an *elevated* session):

```
Invoke-Command { 
  Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' UBR
} -ComputerName remotepc
```

The advantage of this approach over [the OP's own, remote-registry solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47860449/45375) is that you can target multiple machines *in parallel*, up to 32 by default (see [`Get-Help Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1)).

While a remote-registry solution is easier to configure than [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq?view=powershell-5.1), it requires up-front configuration nonetheless: the startup type of the required `RemoteRegistry` service on all target machines defaults to *manual* startup and is therefore *not* running by default.

Here's the **PowerShell equivalent of the OP's own solution**; `$machine` is assumed to contain the name of a target machine:

```
[int] (-split -join 
  (reg query "\\$machine\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v UBR)
)[-1]
```